# problem with SVN commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i want to add new files to my SVN working directory that is trunk folder,

I am adding them but when i wants to commit them so that they can actually be added to SVN it says.

Your working directory is tags.

Attached is the error image. May be i have to change my working directory.
Can some body help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

After you add your files to the workspace, you should run `'svn add'` in order for SVN to know the files were added and to upload them during commit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to the trunk you should use

```
svn switch 'path-to-trunk'
```